# why am I getting \tikzexternaldisable as undefined with pgfSweave?

Tags: r, sweave, tikz

Simple case.

- R-2.13.2
- pgfSweave 1.2.1
- pgf 2.10

I define a very simple file to test with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Testing pgfSweave figures with tikz device}
\begin{document}\maketitle
<<testfigure, fig=T, tikz=T>>=
plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
@
\end{document}
```

but when I run `pgfSweave("test.Rnw", pdf=T, compile.tex=T)`  I get this error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.379 {\tikzexternaldisable
```

And what comes out in the pdf is gibberish.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `\usepackage{tikz}`

Comment: Shouldn't pgfSweave Add this automatically?

Comment: @AndrewRedd -- I'm not sure if pgfSweave **should**, but I too need to include that line in the script.  When I don't, I get just the error message you did.  In addition, both pgfSweave vignettes include `\usepackage{tikz}` directives in their example `.Rnw` scripts.

Comment: Actually I remember `pgfSweave` will automatically add `\usepackage{tikz}` to your tex document, but for some reason, it no longer works. I call stuff like this a `header` component in my package which takes reasonable default values, and users can also define it and will be added before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: pgfSweave will add other stuff to your document but not `\usepackage{tikz}`, the reason being that you may want to add it then use your own tikz libraries.